# Do only Dark Knights acquire vices?

Tags: hai-to-gensou-no-grimgar

It seems that I only ever hear Ranta talking about getting the vice from a monster's kill. I understand that by getting these he is able to level up special skills related to his demon. Are Dark Knights the only class able to acquire vices?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: **yes.**

Slightly longer answer.

In the beginning of the Anime, when the group including Ranta go to get their class specific training, We are greeted with Ranta having a new ability with him. The 'Vice' you mention.
This is because, as we know 'Dark' knights, offer up sacrifices to some form of a 'Dark lord' and have formed a pact.
Just like the Protag (I forget his name) got the ability to see an enemies critical location, and follow a 'stream' of light with his blade, to reach it. Ranta got his own class specific ability.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, yes. Ranta is the only one who talks about vices as he is the only dark knight in the party. Vices are exclusive to Dark Knights. I would think of them as class-exclusive perks found in numerous (MMO)RPGs.

I would provide more information but the only relevant information conveyed in the anime is that:

> When a dark night kills a foe, they can take a part of the enemy with them, be it a toenail or a heart, then they can use these parts to get new perks, like Demon Companion.

(source: http://hai-to-gensou-no-grimgar.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Knight)